# Remove white spaces from number input without converting to string type

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a number like this,
let id = 5;
Is there a way to remove white spaces around the number without converting it into a string first in javascript?

PS: I wanted to delete this question when I discovered the question itself wasn't well thought out before asking but I saw the **'alternatives to deletion'** link so I decided to leave it after reading that incase in the future someone makes same thinking or cognitive error.

Comment: A number value cannot have white space "in" it; it's a number.

Comment: Numbers can't have whitespace. If it has whitespace, it's already a string. If it's a string, use `parseInt()` to transform the string into a number.

Comment: @Pointy ok thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A number has no white space by default. Unless you seem to have some kind of error, you don't have to worry about it.

```
let x =     2    ;
let y=2;

console.log(x === y)
//true
```

If you have any whitespace problems, then your variable is already a string. Try using `parseInt()` to change its type to number, removing the whitespace.